# Misbehaving submenu (js or hover-as-touch) – oddly not replicated [well] on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, css, menu

With help from SO community, I extended a hover-activated menu to a touch-sensitive one.  However on Safari the menu usually doesn't activate at all, and using Firefox and IE on desktop/laptops, the submenu behaves strangely.  As the title says, the same code on jsfiddle works OK; the failure is primarily on my site, [whyisthisnight.com](http://whyisthisnight.com).

[misbehaving.menu.html](http://whyisthisnight.com/misbehaving.menu.html) (which reads [misbehaving.menu.css](http://whyisthisnight.com/misbehaving.menu.css) & [misbehaving.menu.js](http://whyisthisnight.com/misbehaving.menu.js))

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xydrprg7/2/show) (I believe is same code as above)

Problems reported:

- Safari on iPhone (touch): MENU sometimes doesn’t activate at all.
- FF/IE on desktop/FF/IE (hover+clicks): when a submenu item is selected and BACK used for return, the original page's submenu behaves poorly.  Sometimes page opens with submenu expanded and an item selected, or when clicking on menu, an outline frames the previously selected submenu item.
- Sometimes, jsfiddle code misbehaves on Safari/iPhone as follows: Tap MENU, menu expands; tap outside of menu, MENU collapses (so far, OK).  But tap MENU again, submenu unfolds then collapses.  Should stay expanded.

JS uses touchstart and slidedown/slideup to simulate hover state for touchscreens.  I don't know if the binding is wrong, the wrong css elements are referenced in the JS, or what!

Some of the JS is:

```
`$('body').bind('touchstart', function() {});
var down = function() {
$('ul.Menu li ul').slideDown(400) /* default is 400ms */
$('ul.Menu li').one('click', up)
}
var up = function() {
$('ul.Menu li ul').slideUp(400)
$('ul.Menu li').one('click', down)
}
$('ul.Menu li').one('click', function() {
down()
})`
```

I hope someone can discover a simple solution that will work on all platforms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be partially helpful to the community if someone could even edit the jsfiddle to reliably demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @DOC ASAREL: Using your suggestion in JS for triggers, slidedown and binding for touchstart.  But code fails on Safari. Can you look into what will fix?  MENU isn't active, or expands then collapses on Safari.  Seems same code on jsfiddle works; failure is limited to on my site.

Comment: @z0r: Using your JS suggestion also.  See prior comment.  Can you look at this?